# JsonPath expression for extract two dates

Tags: java, jsonpath

I have a JSON with few date nodes. I am reading the json with the help of `JsonPath`. is there any way so that we can write expression and get the difference between two dates. My Json is something like below:

```
"data": [
         {
         "DateA": "2022-11-26Z",
          "otherFactor": 1,
          "DateB": "2022-10-26Z"
         }
        ]
```

I want to calculate difference between two dates using `JsonPath` expression. I haven't found anything in documentation https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Comment: No there isn't !!!

Answer (score 1):

You may consider another library *Josson*

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{\"data\": [" +
    "  {" +
    "    \"DateA\": \"2022-11-26Z\"," +
    "    \"otherFactor\": 1," +
    "    \"DateB\": \"2022-10-26Z\"" +
    "  }" +
    "]}");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "data.untilInDay(" +
    "  DateB.replace('Z','T00:00Z').offsetToLocalDate()," +
    "  DateA.replace('Z','T00:00Z').offsetToLocalDate()" +
    ")");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
[ 31 ]
```